# Session.clear session abandon doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 pages, one login form, one post-login form.

When I post the session over to the post-login form and when I tried to log out, the `session['username']` is not cleared, I can literally enter the URL and it'll direct me back to that page or press the back button.

```
protected void logoutk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

    Session.RemoveAll();

    Session.Contents.RemoveAll();
    Session["username"] = null;
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();

    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     string a = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);

     if (Convert.ToString(Session["username"]) == "" || Session["username"] == null)
     {
       Response.Redirect("login.aspx"); 
     }

     Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);
}
```

Comment: are you using forms authentication?

Comment: I've solved it probably setting session username to null upon login page_load